# Merge Rows in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table like the one below:

```
Customer   |Type     |Count
Joe        |Silver-S |1
Joe        |Silver   |7
Joe        |Gold     |3
Joe        |Gold-S   |2
```

I need to merge this so that it looks like the following:

```
Customer   |Type     |Count
Joe        |Silver   |8
Joe        |Gold     |5
```

Help!

Comment: What is the difference between gold and gold-s.   Do you have a lot of similar patterns, i.e. Bronze-s, Bronze.   What you want is a standard group by operation, but you'll probably need some string manipulation or a case statement to normalize the type field

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned below, the answer from Phil was correct. This answer implied that there was a pattern of -S for every type of scheme there is (e.g. X and then X-S).

Answer (score 3):

```
select Customer, [Type], SUM([Count]) from (
    select Customer, replace([Type], '-S', '') [Type], [COUNT] from Customer
)
t
group by customer, [Type]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution utilising a partition approach:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customer, REPLACE([Type], '-S', '') AS [Type], 
SUM([Count]) OVER (PARTITION BY (SELECT REPLACE([Type], '-S', ''))) AS [Count]
FROM Customer
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select 
    Customer, 
    left([Type],CHARINDEX('-', [type])), 
    sum(COUNT) 

from Customers

group by 
    Customer, 
    left([Type],CHARINDEX('-', [type]));
```

Or this: // edit: this may be slower

```
    select 
        Customer, 
        replace([Type], '-S', ''), 
        sum(COUNT) 

    from Customers

    group by 
        Customer, 
        replace([Type], '-S', '');
```

If this your database project - you should re-design that database and put that "-S" in another field, or avoid situations like this in the future.

Comment: I like this answer the best, because it doesn't rely on the specific substring S or the leading values Gold/Silver. But please combine it with your other answer (or remove your other answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
    select Customer, 
case when Type like 'Silver%' then 'Silver' 
when Type like 'Gold%' then 'Gold' end, sum(Count)
    from table
    group by Customer, 
case when Type like 'Silver%' then 'Silver' 
when Type like 'Gold%' then 'Gold' end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is much cleaner to use a cte in this case. I would do it something like this:

First the test data:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Customer VARCHAR(100),[Type] VARCHAR(10),[Count] INT)

INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
    ('Joe','Silver-S',1),
    ('Joe','Silver',7),
    ('Joe','Gold',3),
    ('Joe','Gold-S',2)
```

The the query:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        tbl.Customer,
        REPLACE(tbl.[Type],'-S','') AS [Type],
        tbl.[Count]
    FROM
        @tbl AS tbl
)
SELECT
    CTE.Customer,
    CTE.[Type],
    SUM(cte.[Count]) AS [Count]
FROM
    CTE
GROUP BY
    CTE.Customer,
    CTE.[Type]
```